# Matlab, maniputale .wav files. Plot signals and listen

Tags: matlab, plot, wav

Hello I have a question.

```
%Problema 3
%A

close all
clear all
clc

[x,fs]=audioread('piano.wav');
x = x';
Nx = length(x) 


caso= menu ('Insira qual dos 4 casos pretende analisar','a=1  t0=50ms','a=1  
t0=500ms','a=0  t0=2ms','a=0  t0=1/2ms','sair');
while caso<5
switch caso   

case 1
    t0 = 50/1000
    a = 1
    tfx=Nx/fs;
    N0=t0*fs
   t = linspace(0,Nx/fs,Nx); 


case 2
    t0 = 500/1000
    a = 1
    tfx=Nx/fs;
   t = linspace(0,Nx/fs,Nx); 
case 3
    t0 = 0
    a = 2
    tfx=Nx/fs;
    t = linspace(0,Nx/fs,Nx); 

case 4
    t0 = 0
    a = 1/2
    tfx=Nx/fs;
   t = linspace(0,Nx/fs,Nx); 
end


   N0=t0*fs





  %função que cria o vetor tempo
%0= tempo de inicio
%fs/Nx=tempo de fim
%Nx= número de amostras

figure
subplot(3,1,1),
plot(t,x)
xlabel('Seconds'); ylabel('Amplitude')


 sound(x,N0)

 caso= menu ('Insira qual dos 4 casos pretende analisar','a=1  t0=50ms','a=1  
 t0=500ms','a=0  t0=2ms','a=0  t0=1/2ms','Sair');     

end
```

And plot this y signal.

How do I apply this changes in the original signal x in matlab script?
So I just have to represent the new signal y, by applying changes to the signal x, changing the a and the t0 but I don't know how to apply those changes
Thanks for your help!!

Comment: This does not seem to be valid Matlab code. Are you familiar with Matlab? If not, I suggest you to first look into the [Matlab basics](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html) or Matlab [starters guide](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/getstart.pdf).

Comment: This is not the complete code. I will put the complete one:

Comment: %Problema 3
%A

close all
clear all
clc

[x,fs]=audioread('piano.wav');
x = x';
Nx = length(x) 


caso= menu ('Insira qual dos 4 casos pretende analisar','a=1  t0=50ms','a=1  t0=500ms','a=0  t0=2ms','a=0  t0=1/2ms','sair');
while caso<5
switch caso   
    
    case 1
        t0 = 50/1000
        a = 1
        tfx=Nx/fs;
        N0=t0*fs
       t = linspace(0,Nx/fs,Nx); 
       case 2
        t0 = 500/1000
        a = 1
        tfx=Nx/fs;
       t = linspace(0,Nx/fs,Nx); 
    case 3
        t0 = 0
        a = 2
        tfx=Nx/fs;
        t = linspace(0,Nx/fs,Nx);

Comment: case 4
        t0 = 0
        a = 1/2
        tfx=Nx/fs;
       t = linspace(0,Nx/fs,Nx); 
end
  

       N0=t0*fs
 




  %função que cria o vetor tempo
%0= tempo de inicio
%fs/Nx=tempo de fim
%Nx= número de amostras

figure
subplot(3,1,1),
plot(t,x)
xlabel('Seconds'); ylabel('Amplitude')


sound(x,N0)

 caso= menu ('Insira qual dos 4 casos pretende analisar','a=1  t0=50ms','a=1  t0=500ms','a=0  t0=2ms','a=0  t0=1/2ms','Sair');     
        
end

Comment: Please edit your original post, instead of putting all this code in a comment.

Comment: Can u get me your email so I can send it by there. It doesn't let me put all the code in the post. This is for a college work, it's nearly all done. I just don't understand a thing here.Thanks for your help

Comment: Or just email me: cabalonline65@gmail.com

Comment: I'm not aware of any code limit in a post. I don't need all the code, just a minimal working example demonstrating your problem is just fine and even better. The goal of stackoverflow is that other people can learn from your problems, which is not possible if you sent me your code privatly.

Comment: @m7913d Did it, it is edited now. Thanks for helping me

Comment: It's not clear to me which transformation you want to apply on `x` to obtain `y`. What is `a`? What is `t0`? Do you want to select a part of the channel and scale it? Please be as concrete as possible and try to provide a [**minimal**  complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: case 1     y(t) = x(t)+x(at-t0)
   

And then make the plot of y signal and plot of the original x signal.

Comment: What may be of interest to you to solve your problem is [interpolation](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) and [vector indexing](https://nl.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html)

Comment: @m7913d Basicly I have to listen the signal y based on the original and plot the signal y based on x. The changes applied are those in the expression: example y(t) = x(t) +x(at-t0) that is different for the 4 cases possible.I just don't know how to scrip that in matlab. Thanks man